# Get link to profile in Socialite?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to get a way to unique identify a Facebook profile using socialite for laravel. I have looked through all of their documentation but it doesn't seem like I can find anything

does anyone know how I am unique identify their profile without it being changed / spoofed like an ID or link to profile that never changes? I have tried doing http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=ID_HERE but no luck

Answer (score 1):

For facebook just add id:

```
// user got from socialite
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

// link to his profile
$userlink = 'https://facebook.com/' . $user->id;
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2054375031451090/?disable_redirect=0 looks like they closed this door. I suppose, it needs an additional request.